# How to search for combination of digits in number (optimizing for speed)?

Tags: python

I'm trying to look for the number of combinations of 7 digit numbers (or more, actually need it to work for 10, but its faster to test with 7) that have 1,3,5,7 in it. Tried a few different methods like using

```
combinations = 0
for combination in itertools.product(xrange(10), repeat=7):
    if all(x in combination for x in (1,3,5,7)):
        combinations += 1
```

However, this next method worked out to be about 4 times faster as it doesnt look for 3,5,7 if 1 is not in the list.

```
combinations = 0

for combination in itertools.product(xrange(10), repeat=7):
    if 1 in combination:
        if 3 in combination:
            if 5 in combination:
                if 7 in combination:
                    combinations += 1
```

I'm sure there is a more cleaver way to achieve this result with numpy or something like that, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for feedback

Comment: You can solve this mathematically rather than brute forcing it.

Comment: Yes, I know its possible to solve this mathematically, I'm just curious of a way to brute force it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `all(x in combination for x in (1,3,5,7))` stops when a condition fails. It's just that it's slower because of the loop/function call overhead on a small list.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre indeed, `all` and `any` are short-circuited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is to find k-digit numbers that contain all the digits 1, 3, 5, 7.

This answer contains a number of solutions, increasing in sophistication and algorithmic efficiency. By the end, we'll be able to, in a fraction of a second, count solutions for huge k, for example 10^12, modulo a large prime.

The section at the end includes tests that provide good evidence that all the implementations are correct.

## Brute force: O(k10^k) time, O(k) space

We'll use this slow approach to test the more optimized versions of the code:

```
def contains_1357(i):
    i = str(i)
    return all(x in i for x in '1357')

def combos_slow(k):
    return sum(contains_1357(i) for i in xrange(10 ** k))
```

## Counting: O(k^4) time, O(k) space

The simplest moderately efficient method is to count. One way to do this is to count all k-digit numbers where the first occurrences of the four special digits appear at digits a, b, c, d.

Given such an a, b, c, d, the digits up to a must be 0,2,4,6,8,9, the digit a must be one of [1, 3, 5, 7], the digits between a and b must be either the same as the digit a or any of the safe digits, the digit b must be one of [1, 3, 5, 7] that's different from the digit at a, and so on.

Summing over all possible a, b, c, d gives the result. Like this:

```
import itertools

def combos0(k):
    S = 0
    for a, b, c, d in itertools.combinations(range(k), 4):
        S += 6 ** a * 4 * 7**(b-a-1) * 3 * 8**(c-b-1) * 2 * 9**(d-c-1) * 10**(k-d-1)
    return S
```

## Dynamic programming: O(k) time, O(k) and then O(1) space

You can solve this more efficiently with dynamic programming: let c[j][i] be the number of i-digit numbers which contain exactly j different digits from (1, 3, 5, 7).

Then c satisfies these recurrence relations:

```
c[0][0] = 1
c[j][0] = 0 for j > 0
c[0][i] = 6 * c[0][i-1] for i > 0
c[j][i] = (6+j)c[j][i-1] + (5-j)c[j-1][i-1] for i, j > 0
```

The final line of the recurrence relations is the hardest one to understand. The first part `(6+j)c[j][i-1]` says that you can make an `i` digit number containing `j` of the digits 1, 3, 5, 7 from a `i-1` digit number containing `j` of the digits 1, 3, 5, 7, and add an extra digit that's either 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9 or any of the digits you've already got. Similarly, the second part `(5-j)c[j-1][i-1]` says that you can take an `i-1` digit number containing `j-1` of the digits 1, 3, 5, 7 and make it an `i`-digit number containing `j` of the special digits by adding one of the digits you haven't already used. There's `5-j` of these.

That leads to this O(k) solution using dynamic programming:

```
def combos(k):
    c = [[0] * (k + 1) for _ in xrange(5)]
    c[0][0] = 1
    for i in xrange(1, k+1):
        c[0][i] = 6 * c[0][i-1]
        for j in xrange(1, 5):
            c[j][i] = (6 + j) * c[j][i-1] + (5-j) * c[j-1][i-1]
    return c[4][k]
```

We can print combos(10):

```
print 'combos(10) =', combos(10)
```

This gives this output:

```
combos(10) = 1425878520
```

The solution above is already fast enough to compute `combos(10000)` in a fraction of a second. But it's possible to optimize the DP solution a little to use O(1) rather than O(k) space by observing that values of `c` depend only on the previous column in the table. With a bit of care (to make sure that we're not overwriting values before they're used), we can write the code like this:

```
def combos2(k):
    c = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for _ in xrange(k):
        for j in xrange(4, 0, -1):
            c[j] = (6+j)*c[j] + (5-j)*c[j-1]
        c[0] *= 6
    return c[4]
```

### Matrix power: O(log k) time, O(1) space.

Ultimately, it's possible to get the result in O(log k) time and O(1) space, by expressing the recurrence relation as a matrix-by-vector multiply, and using exponentiation by squaring. That makes it possible to compute `combos(k) modulo X` even for massive k (here combos(10^12) modulo 2^31 - 1). That looks like this:

```
def mat_vec(M, v, X):
    return [sum(M[i][j] * v[j] % X for j in xrange(5)) for i in xrange(5)]

def mat_mul(M, N, X):
    return [[sum(M[i][j] * N[j][k] for j in xrange(5)) % X for k in xrange(5)] for i in xrange(5)]

def mat_pow(M, k, X):
    r = [[i==j for i in xrange(5)] for j in xrange(5)]
    while k:
        if k % 2:
            r = mat_mul(r, M, X)
        M = mat_mul(M, M, X)
        k //= 2
    return r

def combos3(k, X):
    M = [[6, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4, 7, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 8, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 9, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 10]]
    return mat_vec(mat_pow(M, k, X), [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], X)[4]

print combos3(10**12, (2**31) - 1)
```

Given that your original code struggled for `k=10`, this is quite an improvement!

### Testing

We can test each of the functions against each other (and `combos_slow` for small values). Since `combos3` has an extra arg, we wrap it in a function that passes a modulo that's guaranteed to be larger than the result.

```
def combos3p(k):
    return combos3(k, 10**k)

for c in [combos0, combos, combos2, combos3p]:
    for i in xrange(40 if c == combos0 else 100):
        assert c(i) == (combos_slow if i < 7 else combos)(i)
```

This tests all the implementations against `combos_slow` for i<7, and against each other for 7 <= i < 100 (except for the less efficient `combos0` which stops at 40).

Comment: I don't understand why in the last recurrence, you add both sides of the equation. Wouldn't there be duplicates as they are different ways to look for the same thing ? What am I missing ?

Comment: There are no duplicates in the counting (as demonstrated by the test). Either you add a safe or already-used digit to a (i-1) digit number with j special digits, or you add a not-yet-used special digit to an (i-1) digit number with j-1 special digits.